# iOS 8 landscape app playing embedded youtube video from a uiwebview an only portrait ios app

Tags: ios, ios8, youtube, uiwebview

In my Landscape app you tube open a video from web view . I want handle of you tube player . after playing video app in portrait mode. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you select portrait mode in Xcode?

Comment: Please show some code